# Answer is wrong, suggested edit is right

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

What I should do if answer is clearly wrong, and this is corrected by a suggested edit? Reject or accept? As I understand we cannot change sense of post by editing. But a wrong answer is a worst thing for me.

Answer (score 27):

It depends.

Accept when:

- The mistake is likely due to a typo or some other obviously inadvertent error and is corrected by the edit.

In *all* other cases, e.g.:

- The wrong (version of a) definition was applied;
- The wrong implication is proved;
- A theorem's hypotheses were not fulfilled,

my stance is that the edit should be rejected because the meaning of the post is changed in such a way that only the author could do this.

In these situations, instead of an edit, comments, and possibly downvotes, are in order (but please take the time to write a comment). One should also consider posting one's own (corrected) answer, with attribution to the wrong answer if this is due in some way.

Comment: This answer assumes (correctly IMO but contrary to the OP) that a wrong answer is *not* worse than putting words into someone's mouth. Re: the last paragraph: would you advise always taking this approach with older questions where the user is much less likely to make a revision (because of leaving, apathy, w/e).

Comment: @Eric If the post is old, check the author's profile to get a sense of their level of activity. If they're very inactive (several months not seen), I'd go for comment, downvote, and if necessary and possible try and write a correct answer. A comment gives the poster the chance to come back, fix their post, *and* let you know about it. IMO this incentivises quality.

Comment: Comments and downvotes are not only useful for the original author coming back and making a revision. They help others who come by later to treat the answer with appropriate skepticism.