# I have written a wrong answer and have no means to correct it. What should I do?

Tags: support, specific-question, answers

I wrote an answer but later found that the method used was wrong. Moreover, other answers have already covered other methods and I can't think of a new answer (which could have been used to edit) . What should I do—delete the answer or letting it as it is (or any other suggestion)?

This is the answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4687093/1020656

Comment: If the answer is wrong, you should probably delete it.

Comment: Can you perhaps point to the post for context? Deletion is the reasonable action, but it may be also be the case it can be left, with a proper disclaimer, for future users that might go down the same path as you did, in case this is a particularly tricky problem.

Comment: Perhaps a bit related: [Is sometimes keeping wrong answer reasonable?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3159) You could also check some of the [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3159) - for example, [What should one do appropriately if one finds that he has posted a wrong answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26604).

Comment: @Pedro Yes , it was this post. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4687093/1020656

Comment: Note also that [pity upvoting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2234/242) wrong answers may discourage users from deleting them (the answer had score $-1$ before, now it is  $0),\,$ which is usually not best for site health.

Comment: @BillDubuque Someone may have done that because my mistake maybe common. However, I never asked for any upvotes on any of my post.

Comment: @BillDubuque I've deleted the post. I'll un-delete it in future if I find a new method. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deletion is *usually* the right course of action in this scenario. There are exceptions but I'd say that in this position, when in doubt, delete. After all, you can always undelete later if you find a way to either fix your answer or at least turn it into something that makes forward progress or uncovers a non-obvious obstacle. If the issue was just a misreading of the question or similar, though, you should just delete.