# Deleting incorrect answer when it is adding value to the site

Tags: discussion, answers

Let's say I post an answer to a question which was later pointed out was incorrect in the comments. Should this answer be deleted? I believe that, especially if the mistake is explained and justified by others, the answer (along with the mistake and justification) is adding value to the site.

Should such an answer be deleted since it is incorrect and maybe misleading viewers and the asker? Or should it be left as is (assuming there is justification to the mistake)? This issue arises especially in the cases where the question is up voted a considerable amount of times or even accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: Related older (very old) discussion: [Is sometimes keeping wrong answer reasonable?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3159)